# Do wasteland bonuses apply on quests too?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Some of my pets in Fallout shelter can provide bonuses that describe themselves as working in the Wasteland:

- +X% Wasteland Caps
- +X% Wasteland Weapons & Outfits
- +X% Wasteland Junk

My current understanding is these boost the amount of *stuff* my dwellers find when out exploring the wasteland — and, necessarily, increase the number of shots they get at the small chance of finding really good stuff.

But *quests* narratively take place out in the wasteland too. Do any of these bonuses benefit dwellers on quests in any way, or do they strictly only apply to exploration?